# Serial No. for rows of a table in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have table with 3 columns .

```
S.NO  NAME  AGE
```

I need the serial number to be running as 1.1 1.2 1.3 ... etc (Till the rows end)

Is this possible .?

Comment: Try `=1 + (RowNumber("DataSetName")/10)`

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. This expression has to be added as a calculated field right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by calculated field. You should just put that in the `Expression` box that appears after you click the `fx` button in the `Text Box Properties` window.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked . I now have a another query. If say I group the above table based on AGE . What i need now is that based on each group the row number should generate . say for AGE group 24 - the row numbers should be 1.1,1.2,1.3 etc. n for AGE group XX the row numbers should be 2.1,2.2,2.3 etc and so on.

Comment: Serial numbers under groups are a bit tough. We write some `Custom code` under `Report Properties` to achieve that. If you could wait for a few hours, I can look into it and post as an answer here.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any such example available online??

Comment: Yw. I don't know any examples online. If you could wait for a few hours, I can look into it and post as an answer here.

Comment: That would be great .. thank u so much. I will wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope [this](http://tinypic.com/r/1zmkvt3/5) is what you are looking for.

And [this](http://www.sendspace.com/file/1gombb) is the sample project I created for you. It has the query to create the table called Person, a report project that has an rdl file.

In the rdl file, I've written some code in `Code` tab in `Report Properties` window and in the `Group Properties` window of `Age`, check out the `Variables` tab.

Hope that helps!